# calculating the time diffrence of the Column in hive with the current row and the previous row values?

Tags: sql, hive

Hi I would like to compute the difference of the date time column which will have the value like below I want to find the difference .

```
Name       start_time            rownumber   TIME DIFFERENCE
Vijay      null                       1        0
Vijay      null                       1        0
Vijay      12-03-2018:00:00:00        2        64
Vijay      NULL                       1        0
Vijay      15-03-2018:00:00:00        3        48
VIJAY      17-03-2018:00:00:00        4        null
```

I need a hive command to compute the same

Comment: did you try anything at all? if so, post your attempt please.

Comment: Look up the `lag` function, give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks  Andrew   , I have tried with lag function but the number of rows for the lag function is not fixed in my case it varies if it is fixed it could be the best options unfortunately the data set will not have the same row difference its varying  widely

Answer (score 0):

use LAG over

SELECT name,start_time,
(unix_timestamp(start_time) - unix_timestamp(LAG(start_time,2) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY starttime)))/3600 lag_in_hour
FROM customer;